# Error on data extension InsertData AMPScript function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Could someone explain below error?

**InsertData Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in a non batch context**

I am trying to insert some data into logging Data Extension at the Email send time.

Comment: Probably cant use the insertData in sends due to performance issues but I would like to be sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InsertData function does not work in emails.

> Inserts a row in a data extension. Returns the number of rows
>   affected. **Use this function with landing pages, SMS and MMS messages
>   in MobileConnect, push messages in MobilePush, and messages in
>   GroupConnect.**

Use InsertDE instead.

> Inserts a row in a data extension with the column values listed in
>   name and value pairs. You can include multiple name and value pairs as
>   necessary. Returns no value. **Use this function with email messages at
>   send time only. No value is returned. This function applies to email
>   messages at send time only.**

Source: [InsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertdata.htm), [InsertDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertde.htm)